# How to pass the DropDownList value selected to my controller function to then show the output in a TextArea

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to select the file name in my DropDownList to then call my GetFile function with the name file of the select box to then output it in a TextArea.

But i am unable to pass the data to GetFile( nameFile)

**My DropDownList that contains my xml files name:**

```
<div class="card" style="padding:20px">
    <h4 class="mb-0">Sélection d'un fichier model XML </h4>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ListeFichiers, ((Dictionary<string, string>)Model.ListeFichiers).Select(e => new SelectListItem() { Text = e.Key, Value = e.Value }).ToList(),
 new { @class = "form-control", @id = "listeFichierTransmettre" })
</div>
```

**My GetFile function which takes as a parameter the filename retrieved from DropDownList**

```
public string GetFile(string nomFichier)
{ 
    string path = @"C:\xmlFiles\" + nomFichier;
    string fileContent;
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@path, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        fileContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return fileContent;
}
```

**After that i want to output the GetFile string returned in a TextArea :**

```
    <div class="card-body" id="XMLResult">
        @Html.TextArea("Info", new { cols = "75", rows = "15", @readonly = "readonly", @disabled = "disabled", style = "min-width:100% !important;" })
    </div>
```

**What i tried  but my file name is always null so clearly i am doing something wrong:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#listeFichierTransmettre").change(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Information/GetFile',
            data: $('#listeFichierTransmettre').serialize(),              
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change script to :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#listeFichierTransmettre").change(function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/Information/GetFile',
      data: {
        nomFichier: $("#listeFichierTransmettre").find(":selected").val()
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $("#Info").val(result);
      }
    })
    return false;
  });
});
```